# Get output of a template call in a page from MediaWiki API

Tags: api, mediawiki

I am trying to parse a page on a wikia to get additional information for a `Infobox Book` template that is on the page.  The problem is the I can only get the template's source instead of the transformed template on the page.

I'm using the following url as a base:
`http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&text={{Infobox%20Book}}&generatexml=1`

The documentation doesn't really tell me how to point it to a specific page and parse the transformed template from the page.  Is this even possible or do I need to parse it all myself?

Comment: I dont't get it, what is it that you are trying to do? The API call you give above works perfectly fine for me. Do you want to parse a full page, rather then a piece of wiki text? Then you should use `/index.php?action=render&title=Page_title` (or, if you really need to use the API entry point for some reason, use the workaround `/api.php?action=parse&text={{NS:page}})`

Comment: I want a fully populated template.  This includes the data for the page in question.  The above only gives you the raw text for the template, not the rendered template with source data.  Using this url at the target: `http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn` I would expect the following api call to give me the template rendered with all the books information.  `http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&text={{Infobox%20Book}}&generatexml=1&page=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn`.  This only gives the raw template text though.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how MediaWiki templates work here. Adding `&page=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn` in this case makes no difference whatsoever, because the template `{{Infobox Book}}` does not change according to what page it is on. It only changes with the parameters put in to it, e.g. [`{{Infobox Book|book name=Lost Tribe of the Sith: Skyborn}}`](http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&text={{Infobox%20Book|book%20name=Lost%20Tribe%20of%20the%20Sith:%20Skyborn}}&generatexml=1&page=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn).

Comment: If you want to extract arbitary pieces of data from your wikipages, I would recommend having a look at Semantic MediaWiki, but then you would have to leave Wikia, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a template with the parameters from a given page, you will have to provide those parameters. There is no way for the API to know how the template is used in different pages (it could even be used twice!).

This works:

[`action=expandtemplates&text={{Infobox Book|book name=Lost Tribe of the Sith: Skyborn}}`](http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&text=%7B%7BInfobox%20Book|book%20name=Lost%20Tribe%20of%20the%20Sith%3a%20Skyborn%7D%7D&generatexml=1)

You will, of course have to keep adding all the parameters you want to parse (there are [14](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith%3a_Skyborn?action=edit) in your example).

If you have templates that change automatically depending on which page they are (that is not the case here), e.g. by making use of magic words such as `{{PAGENAME}}`, you can add `&page=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn` to your API call, to set the context the template should be expanded in.

If you to not know the parameters given, you can either:

1. Render the whole page with [index.php?action=render&title=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_Skyborn](http://starwars.wikia.com/index.php?action=render&title=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith%3a_Skyborn), and parse the returned html to carve out the actual infobox
2. Fetch ([action=query&prop=revisions](http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith%3a_Skyborn)) and parse the wikicode to get the parameters to the template, and supply them to the [`expandtemplates` call](http://starwars.wikia.com/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&text=%7B%7BInfobox%20Book|era=%5b%5bOld%20Republic%20era%5d%5d|isbn=978-0-345-51939-9|pages=31|media%20type=%5b%5beBook%5d%5d|release%20date=%5b%5bJuly%2021%5d%5d,%20%5b%5b2009%5d%5d|publisher=%5b%5bDel%20Rey%5d%5d|cover%20artist=%5b%5bDave%20Stevenson%5d%5d|author=%5b%5bJohn%20Jackson%20Miller%5d%5d|image=%5b%5bFile%3aSkyborn.jpg|250px%5d%5d|book%20name=Lost%20Tribe%20of%20the%20Sith%3a%20Skyborn%7D%7D&generatexml=1&page=Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith%3a_Skyborn)
3. Start using an extension like [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki), that allows you to treat your wiki more like a database

1 and 2 can go wrong in any number of ways, of course, as with a wiki you have, by definition, no way of knowing that the content is always entered in a consistent way.

Comment: I would give you more upvotes if I could.  The revisions api call gave me exactly what I needed, thanks!